# Roblox Studio How to toggle print on and off

Tags: lua, roblox

I want the script to print "Printed" when I press P but only if the tool is equipped. If the tool is unequipped I want it to be toggled off.

When I tested my code however the print was not toggled off after I unequipped my tool, it still prints "Printed". What am I doing wrong here?

```
tool = script.Parent
handle = tool.Handle
a = false

tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    if a == false then
        a = true
         game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(function(P)
            if P.KeyCode ==Enum.KeyCode.P then
                print ("Pressed")
            end
        end)
    end

    tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
        if a == true then
            a = false 
        end
    end)
end)
```

Comment: Maybe not the best place for a Roblox question...

Comment: @Michael There's a tag for Roblox specifically; while Roblox questions are allowed here, because of Roblox's target audience questions related to Roblox tend to be lower quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lua once you make a `:Connect` statement that statement will run every time the trigger it's attached to triggers.

This means that once your code has run once and executed that `game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(` call it will run no matter if a equals true or false. What you want is the check to be inside the `:Connect` call.

This is probably what you are looking for here:

```
Tool = script.Parent
Handle = tool.Handle
Run = false

Tool.Equipped:Connect(function()
    Run = true
end)

Tool.Unequipped:Connect(function()
    Run = false
end)

Game:GetService("UserInputService").InputBegan:Connect(function(P)
    if P.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.P and Run = true then
        print ("Pressed")
    end
end)
```

The `Run = true` check means that the print will only run if P is pressed AND the tool is equipped. If you want this to run the other way around you can swap the `true` and `false` assignments around.